# Decode parameters encoded using the JS encodeURIComponent function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, encoding

I have an application that takes text entered by a user and passes it to the server as part of a URL so that an image containing the text can be rendered. The URL parameter is encoded using encodeURIComponent function.

The problem I have is that if the user enters text containing + or foreign characters I cannot get the string decoded correctly server side.

For example, If the string is "François + Anna"

The encoded URL is previewImage.ashx?id=1&text=Fran%25E7ois%2520%2B%2520Anna

On the server

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString( Context.Request.QueryString["text"] )
```

Throws an "Invalid URI: There is an invalid sequence in the string." exception. If I replace the extended character from the string, it is decoded as "Francois + Anna"

However, if I use

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(
    Context.Request.QueryString["text"], System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF7 )
```

the foreign characters are decoded correctly but the encoded + is changed to a space; "François   Anna".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL wasn't encoded correctly to begin with. `previewImage.ashx?id=1&text=Fran%25E7ois%2520%2B%2520Anna` is not the correct URL encoding of `François + Anna`

I believe the correct encoding should have been `previewImage.ashx?id=1&text=Fran%E7ois+%2B+Anna` or `previewImage.ashx?id=1&text=Fran%E7ois%20%2B%20Anna`

Once the encoding has been fixed, then you should be able to retrieve the result via a simple `Context.Request.QueryString["text"]` call.  No need to do anything special.

Comment: Hi Robert, many thanks for your quick reply. I tested the call to encodeURIComponent("François + Anna") on the console and the result was "Fran%C3%A7ois%20%2B%20Anna" which is different from that received on the server. So I did little more digging in the JS and found that as part of the validation the text was being escaped before it was passed to build URL routine. I'm surprised this hasn't caused us problem before. Thanks for the help, couldn't see the wood for the trees.